# Android intent service crashing on firebase database reference

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-intentservice

I am developing an Android application in which I am using an intent service to update locations to my firebase project with a certain periodicity. But it seems that I have hit a wall quite early. When I give the root reference of my firebase database in the service, it crashes.

When I use this code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class LocationUpdater extends IntentService{

    public LocationUpdater() {
        super("LocationUpdater");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        synchronized (this){
            try{
                wait(2000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

which does nothing, it is fine. But when I add this single line:

```
private DatabaseReference mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

just above the LocationUpdater constructor, the app crashes. Any ideas on why this is happening? 
Thanks in advance!

This is the error output in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.mohana.cluster.LocationUpdater: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mohana.cluster. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3168)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mohana.cluster. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.mohana.cluster.LocationUpdater.<init>(LocationUpdater.java:11)
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3165)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Please share your error message when your app crashes from logcat.

Comment: logcat report please

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: You'll need to initialize your `FirebaseApp`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an instance of Firebase without actually initializing it in the first place. Make sure you initialize Firebase before trying to call an instance of it.

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`