# Xamarin push notification plugin not working

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification

I am using https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin
this plugin for push notification but when I deploy app crashes with this error:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.companyname.App7. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Thread finished:  #5
The thread 0x5 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

## need_help

Comment: There's not enough information to help diagnose what is wrong here. Did you follow the error message of not initializing the Firebase Client? Please provide relevant code to the problem as well.

Comment: [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized), you need initializing Firebase Client.