# Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. after updated com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting, android-studio-3.3

I had this bug after updated from `com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1` to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0`

```
Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

For Java projects, they hadn't this problem. I tried to invalidate cache and restart but not resolve.

I'm using:
Android Studio 3.3 Canary 8

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'

      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.61"
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.2.61"
}
```

FirebaseCrashlytics version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having exactly the same problem (altough mine is a java project).

Comment: Having the exact same problem just now. Used the connect button in the Firebase connect tool and that one didn't work either.

Comment: @Granjero I don't know too. I just only updated the old version and java project is good. 
I think we should use the old version 4.0.1 for now. I reported the problem on issues tracker. Maybe, they will check again.
[link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113821952)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. As of now continued using the old version.

Comment: I think this issue will soon be getting a lot more attention. The upgrade to 4.1.0 is also causing 'Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first' run error, addressed in another thread. Developers are also being forced to go back to 4.0.1 for that.

Comment: The one non-auto response I got from repeated attempts to support@fabric.io the error directs you to was that Fabric and Crashlytics are separate teams so they couldn't help me.

Comment: Currently, they updated google service plugin 4.2.0 and seems it works again. You should try.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx~xxxxxx"/>
```

See my related answer to [Default FirebaseApp is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized/52653232#52653232) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't use Admob in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
```

Comment: firebase-crash (deprecated) is **NOT** Crashlytics; do not mix firebase-crash with Crashlytics.

Comment: Sorry buddy. I was unaware since search engine results are displaying `Firebase-Crashlytics` when just searching for `Crashlytics`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was produced because I was picking the wrong APK file. You should pick the **debug apk** (app-debug.apk) instead of the app-name.apk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the meta data for the fabric in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
android:value="xxx6c41xxx6ec601xxxd4xxxa2" />
```

Be guided that the best way is stated below:

Add the Fabric API key to your fabric.properties: apiKey=fabric_api_key

```
# Fabric properties file: app/fabric.properties
apiSecret=xx68f6074dxxxxxc11dxxx97c172e8ebf0
apiKey=xxxe75b4xxxx97e8cxxxx0135e9d46f5a2xxx
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html)

Answer (score 0):

update google plugin from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```