# App just opens and closes even if I initialize the context (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

So I was trying to get my first app up and running and I ran in to a problem when I tried debugging it on my phone.
The error states

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.stuff.morestuff. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.stuff.morestuff.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)
```

And I've tried using `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` but it still throws the same error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //I've tried using this too but it didn't change anything, still the same error
        //FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null){
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Your stacktrace doesn't match your code. The stacktrace says you attempted to initialize `mAuth` during the MainActivity's initialization. Your code shows it being instantiated correctly.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized) link, there's several solution that might work

Comment: Okay so I'm not crazy, that's what I thought yet it seems to do this, do you reckon a restart of the IDE will do?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. **REMARKS Check the comments to the solution if you want to use `4.1.0`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136056/7808468