# Does Firebase Real-Time DB now explicitly require Google Play Services?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

**Background**

I have an older app that still runs properly and is based on an old version of Firebase using the Real-time database functionality.

It runs on my emulator that does not have Google Services available.

**Attempting To Upgrade To New Firebase**

Now, I'm attempting to upgrade that code and I'm running on an emulator image that does not have Google Play services available.

**Installed Firebase Via Android Studio Tools...Firebase...**

I did the installation via the built-in tools from Android Studio (following the latest docs from Firebase).

**The Problem**

Every time the new code based on the latest version of Firebase attempts to call the following line of code I get an error (follows):

```
FirebaseDatabase fbd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

**Error Message**

I get the following error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process . Make
>   sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

**I'm Already Making That Call**

However, I am successfully making the call to FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) previous to that line of code -- I've stepped thru via debugger.

**Unsure About Google Services**

I've seen that some say you have to add a reference to the Google Services but I'm not sure why the Firebase docs don't mention that and the built-in Android Studio tool didn't add it.

Can you point me to a definitive place in the docs where it says you need Google Services?  Has anyone experienced this?  Does anyone know for sure if Google Services are required?

Comment: Realtime Database currently doesn't require Play Services.  The source is open, you can examine it for yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the information. Now, I just wonder why it is crashing on that line with that specific error about not being initialized when I am making the initialization call? I also wonder why the docs are so misleading by showing that Also Google Play Services line.  Well, that's docs for you. :)

Comment: I discovered why it continually failed and wrote up the resolution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized/54810066#54810066)  It seems there is a bit of a problem when including the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' version.  If you don't have a google-services.json it won't warn you.  However, I changed it to 4.0.1 and I got a warning that led me down the correct path and was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I looked more closely at the Firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getInstance(java.lang.String))

Here's a snapshot of the info:

[image: also google play services]

I'm adding that because of that odd **Also: Google Play Services** item.  It's a link that does nothing.  It isn't very helpful, but

I'm *assuming* it means that you do indeed need Google Play Services to be available.

This situation is odd for another reason also, and that is because the call to `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` succeeds without error even though you can basically do nothing after that, since you will have a dependency upon Google Services for the core functionality.

Comment: The realtime database in firebase doesn't need google play services - even though the documents are somewhat misleading.  The real issue here is detailed at my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized/54810066#54810066