# Default FirebaseApp not initialized error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am seeing a few exceptions with the message `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.armoured. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

The stack trace is given below:

```
2019-03-12 20:42:33.607 11511-11511/com.armoured E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.armoured, PID: 11511
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.armoured. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.armoured.fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:59)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

My problem is exactly like the one asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized) question. However, none of the solutions in that question worked for me. I already have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` added to my gradle file. I use `firebase:16.0.3` dependencies in all of my code.

One final detail: I have already added `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` in my fragment. For completeness, I am adding the function where I am getting this error to the question so that you guys might have a context about the error.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    return view;
}
```

EDIT: I am attaching the app level gradle level file as requested.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.armoured"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire build.xml file, even if you think it's correct?

Comment: By build.xml file, I assume you mean the app level gradle file?

Comment: Sorry, build.gradle, the one you modified.

Comment: I have attached it in my edit. I have also linked the question that suggested this change (so that it isn't marked as duplicate).

Comment: @RohitShinde Are you using classpath 4.1 by any chance.?

Comment: I don't think so, but can you tell me a way to check?

Comment: Check your root level `build.gradle`. Add this 

  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

 in the dependencies. Because if you are using 4.1 this is a known issue which was fixed in 4.2.

Comment: @sunilsunny yes, this is resolving it. Changing it to 4.2 from 4.1. If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading `classpath` in root `build.gradle` from `4.1` to `4.2` should fix this issue because 4.1 had an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112716914)  which was fixed in 4.2.

So your dependencies should look something like this.

```
dependencies {
   // other classpaths
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you said that you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to your build.gradle, but I don't see it there.  It should be at the very bottom of your app-level build.gradle.  Perhaps you modified the top level build.gradle instead of the app's.  Not having this line will definitely cause the problem you're seeing.

Also there is no longer any need to use the same version of Firebase dependencies.  They each revision independently now.  If you are just integrating Firebase for the first time, you should use all the latest versions as shown in the [setup documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries).

Comment: Hey Doug, if you look at the very top of the file, I do add the line that you mention.

Comment: And it should be at the very bottom instead, according to the same page of linked instructions.

Comment: Hi Doug, I put it at the very bottom and still it wouldn't work. Sunil's comment above:Changing to 4.2 gradle version instead of using 4.1 helped. I guess this is a bug in the 4.1 version.