# Android app stops working on Emulator when run from in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I'm trying to add firebase to my app but stops working on Emulator when run

my logs:

```
03-21 09:14:40.581 6568-6568/com.example.fireproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fireproject, PID: 6568
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.fireproject. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.fireproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default FirebaseApp is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to use emulator that is backed with `google-play-services`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46246782/5993410)

---

Also As crash explains, try to call

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)
```

before using firebase instance in you activity, you can this in your `Application` class `onCreate` method like this:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getBaseContext())
```

---

And make sure that you correctly apply the **Latest** `google-play-services` plugin

Comment: thanks for answer, im changed com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0 ==> 4.2.0

Comment: You're welcome :) glad I could help