# How to fix java.lang.RuntimeException on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to retrieve the registration token from my device using Firebase in an app which has a TextView that has as a purpose to contain the value of the token in it, when running the app everytime i get a java.lang.RuntimeException error, i added this code `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` as instructed but i still get such error, i'm quite new to Android Studio and Firebase and i'm still experimenting.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        textView= findViewById(R.id.textViewToken);
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                      if(task.isSuccessful()){
                          String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                          textView.setText("Token : " + token);
                        }
                        else
                      {
                          textView.setText("Token Not Generated");
                      }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**Log Trace:**

```
03-31 19:10:19.203 11562-11562/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie, PID: 11562
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: btw its really helpful to have line numbers for source code examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default FirebaseApp is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized)

Comment: post your project build gradle file here too

Comment: @Sam. original post edited.

Comment: @Zoe Please consider unmarking my question as a duplicate, it's obvious that i possibly have all the needed lines of code in my build.gradle for Firebase implementation.

Comment: @Amine you might wanna read the answer before you post a comment that shows you didn't.

Comment: @Zoe If you're talking about FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); this line of code i have it added already, and i already tested connection between Firebase and my app and it checked fine

Comment: @Amine that has nothing to do with code in build.gradle, like you mentioned in your last comment...

Comment: You need to initialize the `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` from class which extends **Application**. Create new class which extends **Application** and do initialization part there, don't forget to add that class reference to `manifest` file

Comment: Fun fact: that's [mentioned in an answer on the dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735303/6296561)

Comment: @Zoe `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` is required... and there is an issue which can be solved by downgrading version from **4.1.0** to **4.0.1**

Comment: @Zoe i did state that i'm a newbie in this and i would obviously go for the highest upvoted answers, the answer you posted has 0 upvotes.

Comment: @Amine Whether you're new or not does not matter - and the highest upvoted answer isn't necessarily the best, or for that matter a correct or updated one. If you think you can use "I'm new" to either SO or a tech as an excuse for anything, you are *very* wrong.

Comment: @Amine no, I care about keeping SO what it's intended - [a high-quality library of questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382032/6296561). Which includes closing duplicates. Also, I've flagged your last comment.

Comment: @Sam. Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> For a vast majority of apps, `FirebaseInitProvider` will handle the initialization of Firebase for the default project that it's configured to work with, via the data contained in the app's `google-services.json` file.
>
> In the event that an app requires access to another Firebase project in addition to the default project, `initializeApp(Context, FirebaseOptions, String)` must be used to create that relationship programmatically.

If you are using this app in two different projects then you need to use `initializeApp()`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

Also update your Google service version to `4.2.0` as `4.1.0` had configuration issues.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end of app gradle:

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
     ...
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```