# How can i count a query / dataSnapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show the number of active users in my StartActivity. The users are divided into two groups: players and spectators. I tried it in my database with a Boolean value. How can I show / count the users?

**Database:**
[Firebase Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLmaA.png)
**StartActivity:** 
[XML Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjBX1.png)

**Here is my `StartAytivity.class` code:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        Button run = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        watcher = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        player = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        onlineCount();
    }
```

**Here is my OnlineCount code:**

```
public void onlineCount(){
        //watcher
        refwatcher = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("online_list")
                .child("watcher")
                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child("online");

        Query query = refwatcher.orderByChild("online").equalTo(true);


        refwatcher.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                wcount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                watcher.setText(getString(wcount) + getText(R.string._29_349_watchers_online));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //player
        DatabaseReference refplayer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("online_list").child("player");

        refplayer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                player.setText("1" + getText(R.string._230_player_online));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Here is my debug code:**

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at com.bbinktattoo.nerve.StartActivity.onlineCount(StartActivity.java:65)
        at com.bbinktattoo.nerve.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
```

Comment: Please search for the error message before posting a question about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the problem your question implies. You want to know how to count your database entries. Every element in firebase is a node and can have **n** children and has exactly **1** parent. The relation ship between a node and its parent is **1:1** while the relation ship between the node and its children is **1:n**.

So if you want to count the amount of elements you have to call the getChildren() Method on the parent node, which will return **n** references to the **n** nodes.

However, it seems like you're not initializing the Firebase SDK as supposed to. Make sure you read and understand the related docs 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

I would guess that you have not set the correct configuration parameters

Comment: You are linking to the wrong docs :) He's using Android, not the admin SDK

Comment: you're right, fixed it :-) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not the counting itself but Firebase seems improperly setup in your app. Make sure to follow the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) step by step. Also check Logcat for errors and warnings from Firebase, usually there is something useful.