# Firebase RecyclerView Data Retrieve Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code that extracts data from firebase and stored to recycler view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<DataSetFire> arrayList;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataSetFire> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetFire, FirebaseViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        arrayList = new ArrayList<DataSetFire>();


        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSetFire>().setQuery(databaseReference, DataSetFire.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetFire, FirebaseViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FirebaseViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataSetFire model) {


                holder.Username.setText(model.getUsername());
                holder.Phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                holder.Query.setText(model.getQuery());
                // Below line redirects to new layout which shows detailed queries.
                /*holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Query",model.getQuery());

                    }
                });*/

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FirebaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                return new FirebaseViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false));
            }
        };


        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

While Running the app the followin error shows up

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.creativebeastadmin, PID: 26348
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.creativebeastadmin/com.example.creativebeastadmin.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.creativebeastadmin. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.creativebeastadmin. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:67)
        at com.example.creativebeastadmin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)

Comment: Your error is very clear: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized

Comment: How do I fix it? I am very new to Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.creativebeastadmin. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. Everything is written here, you need to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp (Context)