# React native push notification for local notification without firebase not possible

Tags: android, react-native

React Native project with push notifications, I use [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

I follow [this](https://apiko.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications/) tutorial.

I only need local notifications. But if I run this project I get an error `default firebaseapp is not initialized in this process`.

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085096) answer and get a google service.json from firebase to make it start (notification don't show up unfortunately). But is this also possible without firebase?

Answer (score 1):

```
requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios', This line you have to add 
import { Platform} from 'react-native';    
PushNotification.configure({
    
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log("TOKEN:", token);
      },

      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);


      },

      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },


      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',// This line you have to add //import Platform from react native
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to push local notification without firebase. I implemented it in one of my projects. You can take reference from [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1763#issuecomment-735281950) comment.

And also you don't have to call register methods from `example` which is available in react-native-push-notifications repo.

PS: As author did not marked any of the above answers as resolved. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) package does work without firebase, after installing and setting up clear gradle cache.

On Windows:
gradlew cleanBuildCache

On Mac or UNIX:
./gradlew cleanBuildCache

Comment: for remote notification it is using firebase