Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    initComponents();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnSuccessListener(s -> {
        Log.d("TOKEN", "Token" + s);
        Exponea.INSTANCE.handleNewToken(getApplicationContext(), s);
    });    
}

I have used this code to firebase messaging service and try to get token .
in build.gradle :
//firebase
app level gradle
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

project level gradle :
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'

When i try to run code, at  runtime i am getting below error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.versatilemobitech.prive. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

while i already initializeApp in Splash activity.
Can anyone help or suggest what i am doing wrong?

Did Yakubu's answer solve the problem?

The issue is likely because firebase is been access before being initialized even though it is initialized in onCreate.
Try to move FirebaseApp.initializeApp to application entry point.
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Initialize Firebase
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    }
}

in your AndroidManifest.xml, register MyApp
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    >
  
</application>

Also ensure you have this in build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'

  // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  // 
}

You can read more here Firebase

Thanks for answer this solution  not working this i already tried before also same issue is coming

could you paste your full implementation

also have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized
