Problem with initializing Facebook in untiy
Hello there I am trying to make a 2d Android game in unity , and I want to incorporate Facebook login with firebase auth as a login method , I am using lasts stable unity version 2022.3.32f1 and last stable Facebook sdk17.0.1 and last firebase auth 12.0.0
Now when I run the game in unity editor it works fine and every things run smoothly, but when I build the apk and run it on my Android device the firebase auth not intialized (i removed facebook sdk till I find the solution)
I searched for an answer and didn't find any thing
my logcat :

0001/01/01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of main
2024/06/13 21:33:41.916 14538 14538 Info crewMultiplayer Using
CollectorTypeCC GC. 2024/06/13 21:33:41.922 14538 14538 Error
crewMultiplayer Not starting debugger since process cannot load the
jdwp agent. 2024/06/13 21:33:41.929 14538 14538 Info MessageMonitor
Load libmiui_runtime 2024/06/13 21:33:41.956 14538 14538 Debug
CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID
10251; state: ENABLED 2024/06/13 21:33:41.963 14538 28819 Debug
AppScoutStateMachine 14538-ScoutStateMachinecreated 2024/06/13
21:33:41.963 14538 14538 Debug nativeloader Configuring
classloader-namespace for other apk
/data/app/~~T3H8kg6FqRYJAT36XKHs7g==/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer-4_zQHU9EUTa4jGOs6fqUhQ==/base.apk.
target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=,
library_path=/data/app/~~T3H8kg6FqRYJAT36XKHs7g==/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer-4_zQHU9EUTa4jGOs6fqUhQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~T3H8kg6FqRYJAT36XKHs7g==/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer-4_zQHU9EUTa4jGOs6fqUhQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer
2024/06/13 21:33:41.969 14538 14538 Info Perf Connecting to perf
service. 2024/06/13 21:33:41.973 14538 14538 Verbose
GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE Developer option for
'com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer' set to: 'default' 2024/06/13
21:33:41.973 14538 14538 Verbose GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE
GameManagerService for com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer: false 2024/06/13
21:33:41.973 14538 14538 Verbose GraphicsEnvironment Updatable
production driver is not supported on the device. 2024/06/13
21:33:41.976 14538 14538 Info ForceDarkHelperStubImpl initialize for
com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer , ForceDarkOrigin 2024/06/13 21:33:41.977
14538 14538 Debug crewMultiplayer JNI_OnLoad success 2024/06/13
21:33:41.977 14538 14538 Info MiuiForceDarkConfig setConfig
density:2.750000, mainRule:0, secondaryRule:0, tertiaryRule:0
2024/06/13 21:33:41.978 14538 14538 Debug NetworkSecurityConfig No
Network Security Config specified, using platform default 2024/06/13
21:33:41.978 14538 14538 Debug NetworkSecurityConfig No Network
Security Config specified, using platform default 2024/06/13
21:33:41.980 14538 14538 Warn FirebaseApp Default FirebaseApp failed
to initialize because no default options were found. This usually
means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your
gradle project. 2024/06/13 21:33:41.980 14538 14538 Info
FirebaseInitProvider FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2024/06/13 21:33:41.983 14538 14538 Debug MiuiMultiWindowAdapter
MiuiMultiWindowAdapter::getFreeformVideoWhiteListInSystem::LIST_ABOUT_SUPPORT_LANDSCAPE_VIDEO
= [com.hunantv.imgo.activity, com.tencent.qqlive, com.qiyi.video, com.hunantv.imgo.activity.inter, com.tencent.qqlivei18n,
com.iqiyi.i18n, tv.danmaku.bili] 2024/06/13 21:33:41.992 14538 14538
Warn libc Access denied finding property
"ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict" 2024/06/13 21:33:41.997 14538 14538
Debug IS_CTS_MODE false 2024/06/13 21:33:41.997 14538 14538 Debug
MULTI_WINDOW_ENABLED false 2024/06/13 21:33:41.999 14538 14538 Debug
DecorView[] getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1 2024/06/13
21:33:42.057 14538 14538 Info IL2CPP JNI_OnLoad 2024/06/13
21:33:42.073 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[] getWindowModeFromSystem
windowmode is 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.073 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[]
updateDecorCaptionStatus windowMode is 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.100 14538
14538 Debug SurfaceView UPDATE null, mIsCastMode = false 2024/06/13
21:33:42.104 14538 14538 Error SurfaceSyncer Failed to find sync for
id=0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.117 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceView UPDATE
Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity])/@0xca15b60,
mIsProjectionMode = false 2024/06/13 21:33:42.117 14538 14538 Debug
SurfaceControl nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection
2024/06/13 21:33:42.118 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceControl
nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection 2024/06/13
21:33:42.118 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceControl
nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection 2024/06/13
21:33:42.124 14538 14538 Error SurfaceSyncer Failed to find sync for
id=0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.130 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[]
onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true 2024/06/13 21:33:42.131 14538
14538 Info HandWritingStubImpl refreshLastKeyboardType: 1 2024/06/13
21:33:42.131 14538 14538 Info HandWritingStubImpl
getCurrentKeyboardType: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.143 14538 28842 Info
Unity MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator. 2024/06/13
21:33:42.152 14538 14538 Info HandWritingStubImpl
getCurrentKeyboardType: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.188 14538 28842 Info
Unity SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 11198mb
2024/06/13 21:33:42.188 14538 28842 Info Unity SystemInfo ARM
big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
2024/06/13 21:33:42.188 14538 28842 Info Unity ApplicationInfo
com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer version 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.188 14538
28842 Info Unity Built from '2022.3/staging' branch, Version
'2022.3.32f1 (c8300dc0a3fa)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend
'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Enabled' 2024/06/13 21:33:42.202
14538 14538 Debug DecorView[] getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
2024/06/13 21:33:42.202 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[]
updateDecorCaptionStatus windowMode is 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.336 14538
28842 Info Unity Company Name: Youleen 2024/06/13 21:33:42.336 14538
28842 Info Unity Product Name: Screw Multiplayer 2024/06/13
21:33:42.342 14538 28842 Debug vulkan searching for layers in
'/data/app/~~T3H8kg6FqRYJAT36XKHs7g==/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer-4_zQHU9EUTa4jGOs6fqUhQ==/lib/arm64'
2024/06/13 21:33:42.342 14538 28842 Debug vulkan searching for layers
in
'/data/app/~~T3H8kg6FqRYJAT36XKHs7g==/com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer-4_zQHU9EUTa4jGOs6fqUhQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a'
2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 ===== BEGIN DUMP
OF OVERRIDDEN SETTINGS ===== 2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info
AdrenoVK-0 ===== END DUMP OF OVERRIDDEN SETTINGS ===== 2024/06/13
21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 QUALCOMM build          :
329cf4c2a7, I63533b1e29 2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info
AdrenoVK-0 Build Date              : 01/31/23 2024/06/13 21:33:42.349
14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Shader Compiler Version : EV031.35.01.12
2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Local Branch
:  2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Remote Branch
: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.14.11.00.00.571.148 2024/06/13
21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Remote Branch           :
NONE 2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Reconstruct
Branch      : NOTHING 2024/06/13 21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info
AdrenoVK-0 Build Config            : S P 10.0.7 AArch64 2024/06/13
21:33:42.349 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Driver Path             :
/vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.adreno.so 2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842
Info AdrenoVK-0 QUALCOMM build          : 329cf4c2a7, I63533b1e29
2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Build Date
: 01/31/23 2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Shader
Compiler Version : EV031.35.01.12 2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842
Info AdrenoVK-0 Local Branch            :  2024/06/13 21:33:42.352
14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Remote Branch           :
refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.14.11.00.00.571.148 2024/06/13
21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Remote Branch           :
NONE 2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Reconstruct
Branch      : NOTHING 2024/06/13 21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info
AdrenoVK-0 Build Config            : S P 10.0.7 AArch64 2024/06/13
21:33:42.352 14538 28842 Info AdrenoVK-0 Driver Path             :
/vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.adreno.so 2024/06/13 21:33:42.370 14538 28842
Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38 2024/06/13
21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.372 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38 2024/06/13 21:33:42.373
14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.373 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.384 14538 28920 Debug Choreographer Attaching thread to JVM for AChoreographer 2024/06/13
21:33:42.385 14538 28842 Verbose SwappyVk SwappyVk initialized for
VkDevice 0xb400007c13202660 using VK_GOOGLE_display_timing on Android
2024/06/13 21:33:42.385 14538 28842 Info SwappyVk Returning refresh
duration of 8333333 nsec (approx 120.000005 Hz) 2024/06/13
21:33:42.394 14538 28842 Verbose MediaRouter Selecting route:
RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null,
category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO
ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
presentationDisplay=null } 2024/06/13 21:33:42.394 14538 28842 Info
MediaRouter Skip setBluetoothA2dpOn(): types=8388615,
isPlaybackActive()=false, BT route=null 2024/06/13 21:33:42.400 14538
28842 Warn AidlConversion
aidl2legacy_AudioChannelLayout_audio_channel_mask_t: no legacy output
audio_channel_mask_t found for AudioChannelLayout{layoutMask: 16}
2024/06/13 21:33:42.410 14538 28842 Debug crewMultiplayer
PlayerBase::PlayerBase() 2024/06/13 21:33:42.410 14538 28842 Debug
crewMultiplayer TrackPlayerBase::TrackPlayerBase() 2024/06/13
21:33:42.411 14538 28842 Info libOpenSLES Emulating old channel mask
behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based
on channel count of 2) 2024/06/13 21:33:42.411 14538 28842 Debug
AudioTrack set(sessionId=26633) 2024/06/13 21:33:42.411 14538 28842
Debug AudioTrack set(): streamType 3, sampleRate 48000, format 0x1,
channelMask 0x3, frameCount 0, flags #104, notificationFrames -10,
sessionId 26633, transferType 0, uid -1, pid -1 2024/06/13
21:33:42.411 14538 28842 Warn AudioTrack set(): notificationFrames=-10
clamped to the range -1 to -8 2024/06/13 21:33:42.423 14538 28842 Info
AudioTrack createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST successful;
frameCount 0 -> 1536 2024/06/13 21:33:42.426 14538 28842 Debug
AudioTrack start(2111): prior state:STATE_STOPPED 2024/06/13
21:33:42.427 14538 14538 Debug MediaRouter onRestoreRoute() :
route=RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null,
category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO
ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
presentationDisplay=null } 2024/06/13 21:33:42.427 14538 14538 Verbose
MediaRouter Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null,
status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System
types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
presentationDisplay=null } 2024/06/13 21:33:42.571 14538 28842 Error
qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38 2024/06/13
21:33:42.571 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:33:42.571 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:33:42.571 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:33:42.571 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38 2024/06/13 21:33:42.572
14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:33:42.572 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.573 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:33:42.573 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:42.592 14538 28842 Verbose SwappyVk SwappyVk initialized for VkDevice 0xb400007c13202660 using
VK_GOOGLE_display_timing on Android 2024/06/13 21:33:42.592 14538
28842 Info SwappyVk Returning refresh duration of 8333333 nsec (approx
120.000005 Hz) 2024/06/13 21:33:43.435 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 1s(f:0 m:1000 s:0 k:1000) : pid 14538 uid 10251
sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:44.436 14538
28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 2s(f:0 m:2000 s:0
k:2000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:45.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 3s(f:0 m:3000 s:0 k:3000) : pid 14538 uid 10251
sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:46.436 14538
28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 4s(f:0 m:4000 s:0
k:4000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:47.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 5s(f:0 m:5000 s:0 k:5000) : pid 14538 uid 10251
sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:48.436 14538
28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 6s(f:0 m:6000 s:0
k:6000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity AndroidVideoMedia: No
tracks in sharedassets1.resource 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895
Warn Unity  #0 0x7baa675a1c (libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13
21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #1 0x7baaaa66e8 (libunity.so) ?
0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #2 0x7baa81dc94
(libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #3
0x7baa81d084 (libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895
Warn Unity  #4 0x7baa817150 (libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13
21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #5 0x7baa8131f4 (libunity.so) ?
0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #6 0x7baa4a6720
(libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #7
0x7baa4a6c9c (libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895
Warn Unity  #8 0x7baa4a73f4 (libunity.so) ? 0x0 2024/06/13
21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #9 0x7baa54b30c (libunity.so) ?
0x0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  #10 0x7cc4d3c5c8
(libc.so) __pthread_start(void*) 0xd0 2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538
28895 Warn Unity  #11 0x7cc4cd5fbc (libc.so) __start_thread 0x44
2024/06/13 21:33:48.859 14538 28895 Warn Unity  2024/06/13
21:33:48.956 14538 29172 Error firebase Failed to read Firebase
options from the app's resources. Either make sure
google-services.json is included in your build or specify options
explicitly. 2024/06/13 21:33:48.974 14538 29172 Info IL2CPP Locale
en-US 2024/06/13 21:33:49.018 14538 28842 Error firebase Failed to
read Firebase options from the app's resources. Either make sure
google-services.json is included in your build or specify options
explicitly. 2024/06/13 21:33:49.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 7s(f:0 m:7000 s:0 k:7000) : pid 14538 uid 10251
sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:50.436 14538
28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 8s(f:0 m:8000 s:0
k:8000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:51.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 9s(f:0 m:9000 s:0 k:9000) : pid 14538 uid 10251
sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:52.436 14538
28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 10s(f:0 m:10000 s:0
k:10000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:53.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 11s(f:0 m:11000 s:0 k:11000) : pid 14538 uid
10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:54.436
14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 12s(f:0 m:12000
s:0 k:12000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:55.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 13s(f:0 m:13000 s:0 k:13000) : pid 14538 uid
10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:56.436
14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 14s(f:0 m:14000
s:0 k:14000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:57.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 15s(f:0 m:15000 s:0 k:15000) : pid 14538 uid
10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:58.436
14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 16s(f:0 m:16000
s:0 k:16000) : pid 14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
2024/06/13 21:33:59.436 14538 28927 Debug AudioTrack
[audioTrackData][mute] 17s(f:0 m:17000 s:0 k:17000) : pid 14538 uid
10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13 21:33:59.938
14538 28842 Debug crewMultiplayer PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
2024/06/13 21:33:59.938 14538 28842 Debug AudioTrack
stop(sessionID=26633) 2024/06/13 21:33:59.938 14538 28842 Debug
AudioTrack stop(2111): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE 2024/06/13
21:33:59.938 14538 28842 Debug AudioTrack stop(2111): called with
834432 frames delivered 0001/01/01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  ---------
beginning of system 2024/06/13 21:33:59.945 14538 14538 Warn Activity
PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity
com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
onPause took 53ms 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info
AdrenoGLES-0 QUALCOMM build                   : 329cf4c2a7,
I63533b1e29 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0
Build Date                       : 01/31/23 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978
14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version:
EV031.35.01.12 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0
Local Branch                     :  2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538
29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Remote Branch                    :
refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.14.11.00.00.571.148 2024/06/13
21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Remote Branch
: NONE 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0
Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978
14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Build Config                     : S P
10.0.7 AArch64 2024/06/13 21:33:59.978 14538 29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Driver Path                      :
/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so 2024/06/13 21:33:59.986 14538
29584 Info AdrenoGLES-0 PFP: 0x016dc094, ME: 0x00000000 2024/06/13
21:34:00.011 14538 29584 Warn libc Access denied finding property
"vendor.migl.debug" 2024/06/13 21:34:00.018 14538 29584 Error libEGL
pre_cache appList: ,, 2024/06/13 21:34:00.031 14538 29584 Error libEGL
pre_cache appList: ,, 2024/06/13 21:34:00.141 14538 14538 Error
BLASTBufferQueue VRI[UnityPlayerActivity]#0 Applying
pending transactions on dtor 1 2024/06/13 21:34:00.146 14538 14538
Debug DecorView[] onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false 2024/06/13
21:34:00.162 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[] getWindowModeFromSystem
windowmode is 1 2024/06/13 21:34:00.162 14538 14538 Debug DecorView[]
updateDecorCaptionStatus windowMode is 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.571 14538
28925 Debug AppScoutStateMachine 14538-ScoutStateMachinecreated
2024/06/13 21:34:07.590 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceView UPDATE
Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.Youleen.ScrewMultiplayer/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity])/@0xa4b1b23,
mIsProjectionMode = false 2024/06/13 21:34:07.590 14538 14538 Debug
SurfaceControl nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection
2024/06/13 21:34:07.590 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceControl
nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection 2024/06/13
21:34:07.591 14538 14538 Debug SurfaceControl
nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection 2024/06/13
21:34:07.591 14538 14538 Error SurfaceSyncer Failed to find sync for
id=0 2024/06/13 21:34:07.591 14538 14538 Error SurfaceSyncer Failed to
find sync for id=1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.591 14538 14538 Error
SurfaceSyncer Failed to find sync for id=2 2024/06/13 21:34:07.671
14538 14538 Debug DecorView[] onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
2024/06/13 21:34:07.671 14538 14538 Info HandWritingStubImpl
refreshLastKeyboardType: 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.671 14538 14538 Info
HandWritingStubImpl getCurrentKeyboardType: 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.680
14538 28842 Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38
2024/06/13 21:34:07.680 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:34:07.680 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:34:07.680 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:34:07.680 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.681 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.681 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc GetGpuPixelFormat: No map for format: 0x38 2024/06/13 21:34:07.682
14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<validate_memory_layout_input_parmas:1970>: Unknown Format 0
2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error AdrenoUtils
<adreno_init_memory_layout:4720>: Memory Layout input parameter
validation failed! 2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error qdgralloc
GetGpuResourceSizeAndDimensions Graphics metadata init failed
2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error Gralloc4 isSupported(1, 1,
56, 1, ...) failed with 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error
GraphicBufferAllocator Failed to allocate (4 x 4) layerCount 1 format
56 usage b00: 1 2024/06/13 21:34:07.682 14538 28842 Error
AHardwareBuffer GraphicBuffer(w=4, h=4, lc=1) failed (Unknown error
-1), handle=0x0 2024/06/13 21:34:07.715 14538 28842 Verbose SwappyVk SwappyVk initialized for VkDevice 0xb400007c13202660 using
VK_GOOGLE_display_timing on Android 2024/06/13 21:34:07.715 14538
28842 Info SwappyVk Returning refresh duration of 8333333 nsec (approx
120.000005 Hz) 2024/06/13 21:34:07.722 14538 28842 Debug AudioTrack start(2111): prior state:STATE_STOPPED 2024/06/13 21:34:07.723 14538
14538 Debug MediaRouter onRestoreRoute() : route=RouteInfo{
name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{
name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO
groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO
ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null } 2024/06/13
21:34:07.723 14538 14538 Verbose MediaRouter Selecting route:
RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null,
category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO
ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
presentationDisplay=null } 2024/06/13 21:34:08.238 14538 28927 Debug
AudioTrack [audioTrackData][mute] 18s(f:0 m:18000 s:0 k:500) : pid
14538 uid 10251 sessionId 26633 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1 2024/06/13
21:34:08.495 14538 14538 Warn MirrorManager this model don't Support
2024/06/13 21:34:09.034 14538 28842 Debug crewMultiplayer
PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer 2024/06/13 21:34:09.034 14538 28842
Debug AudioTrack stop(sessionID=26633) 2024/06/13 21:34:09.034 14538
28842 Debug AudioTrack stop(2111): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE 2024/06/13
21:34:09.034 14538 28842 Debug AudioTrack stop(2111): called with
56064 frames delivered 2024/06/13 21:34:09.044 14538 14538 Debug
DecorView[] onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false


If I remember correctly, it should tell you the reason why it is not getting initialized. Its been a while since I worked with Facebook SDK on mobile.
Ensure that you have correctly entered APP IDs or keys to the Facebook settings in the Unity editor as well.

Now I removed the Facebook sdk and tried to intialized only firebase auth , it runs very good in unity editor but when I build the apk it start but never run I think the apk can't reach the Google service Jason file and help ?

Can you try to post the logs of the game while it is running on device? You can use tools like adb for this. It should tell you the exceptions related to it.

i have added my logcat

In the log it says FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project. 2024/06/13 21:33:41.980 14538 14538 Info FirebaseInitProvider FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
Check out the following threads, they can help you with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/660
